# What is the cost of making Game of Thrones each episode?

Tags: production, game-of-thrones

I'm wondering by seeing the richness of episodes in Game of Thrones. What is the average making cost of a single Game of Thrones episode?

Answer (score 14):

According to a [very recent (2 days old) Guardian article](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/tvandradioblog/2015/apr/15/periscope-tv-piracy-game-of-thrones):

> Game of Thrones costs HBO something in the region of **$6m an episode** to produce.

And plenty of [sources](http://www.eonline.com/news/318306/holy-flaming-warships-how-expensive-is-game-of-thrones-anyway) confirm it. A [Yahoo TV article](https://www.yahoo.com/tv/bp/burning-question--how-does--game-of-thrones--thrive-despite-high-per-episode-costs-234743521.html) adds:

> some episodes of "Game of Thrones" actually have cracked that obscene average budget of $6 million per. That Battle of Blackwater episode? Where the Imp leaked a ship's worth of highly flammable Mountain Dew into the harbor and blew up half of Stannis's army? That cost a reported $8 million.

The pilot was also extravagant, [costing more than $10m](http://www.ibtimes.com/game-thrones-big-budgets-bring-huge-success-how-hbo-series-makes-money-high-cost-episode-1658966).

Comment: I know whose fingers i will be chopping first when i ascend to the iron throne.

Comment: Hope it is not Walt, we will not get answer easily after that